# What does ampersand mean at the end of a shell script line?

Tags: shell

```
sh sys-snap.sh &
```

What is `sh`?
What is `sys-snap.sh`?
Why I should put `&` at the end of the line?
Can anyone explain the syntax?

Without the `&` the script won't go back to the prompt till I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.
With `&` I can press enter and it works.

Comment: is the double ampersand `&&` different from a single ampersand `&`?

Comment: @CharlieParker Have you ever found an answer to that? I'm trying to figure out the difference myself. (Edit: Nevermind, found it further down)

Comment: Yes, they are completely different. A && B means "run command B if command A succeeded", and A || B means "run command B if command A failed".

Examples: 'cd tmp && ls' will run ls only if folder tmp exists.
Or in a script: 'cd foobar || exit 10' will stop the execution (exit) if folder foobar doesnt' exist.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

`sh` is the default [Bourne-compatible shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell) (usually bash or dash)

`sys-snap.sh` is a shell script, which contains commands that `sh` executes.
As you do not post its content, I can only guess from its name, what it does.
I can find a script related to CPanel with the same file name, that make a log file with all current processes, current memory usage, database status etc.
If the script starts with a [shebang line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) (`#!/bin/sh` or similar), you can make it executable with `chmod +x sys-snap.sh` and start it directly by using `./sys-snap.sh` if it is in the current directory.

With `&` the process starts in the background, so you can continue to use the shell and do not have to wait until the script is finished.
If you forget it, you can stop the current running process with `Ctrl-Z` and continue it in the background with  `bg` (or in the foreground with `fg`).
For more information, see [job control](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Basics.html)

Comment: `sh` in usually only `bash` or `dash` in Linux based systems (or recent OS/X). On BSDs, it's usually another variant of Ash (dash is based on NetBSD sh, itself based on the Almquist Shell) or a pdksh derivative. On commercial Unices, it's generally ksh88.

Comment: @jofel: What if the below script is running and by mistaken I have executed Ctrl-C. Will my script will execute or it will get terminated?
Ex: sh sys-snap.sh &

Comment: @Hussain7 Ctrl-C is sent always to the current process in the foreground. If the shell-script is started with `&` and therefore in the background, you get only a new shell prompt.

Comment: is the double ampersand `&&` different from a single ampersand `&`?

Comment: @CharlieParker Yes, "&&" is the "and" function. The command after && is called only when the command before succeeds. Example "true && echo works" output "works, but  "false && echo no output" does not call the echo function.

Comment: @jofel so if you did `echo works && cmd` it would always call `cmd` because echo always returns true? I guess I am trying to think what happens if the boolean is on the other side as in `cmd && BOOL`. I am assuming that you said true or false as a simplification, the boolean is actually the output of a command? Since I've seen `cmd1 && cmd2`.

Comment: @CharlieParker Yes, for  `&&`, the shell uses the return value of a process as boolean (zero=true, non-zero=false). `true` is a simple program which returns always zero, `false` returns always 1 (i.e. non-zero).

Comment: @jofel, Does `&` have a different meaning in MAC Applescript?

Comment: @Pacarier In Applescript, the `&` is used to [concatenate strings](https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/mac-os-x/applescript-concatenate-strings) and need to be escaped to get different behavior (but this is offtopic here)

Answer (score 128):

This is known as `job control` under unix. The `&` informs the shell to put the command in the background. This means it continues to run the `sys-snap.sh` command but returns you to your shell to allows you to continue doing parallel commands.

You can see the list of jobs presently running with the `jobs` command. You can return to the command (bring to the 'foreground) with use of the `fg` command. Which pulls the command back to the state where you see no prompt and you have to issue <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> to *kill* the process. You can however *suspend* (pause) that process, issuing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>. This will pause `sys-snap.sh` and return you to your prompt. You can then background it (as though you had issued it *with* the `&`) with the `bg` command, and it will *resume* running from it's paused state the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> had put it in.

Note that you can have more than one job at a time (as shown by `jobs`):

```
[1]-  Running          sys-snap.sh &
[2]+  Running          another-script.sh &
```

You can background and foreground them using their job number, `%1` will be `sys-snap.sh` and `%2` will be `another-script.sh`. If you use `fg` or `bg` without arguments it will action the command on the job marked by `+` in the `jobs` output above.

`fg %1`

will put `sys-snap.sh` back into the foreground, whilst leaving `another-script.sh` in the background.

You can issue the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> sequence to running jobs without having to foreground them with the `kill` command, `kill %1` will send the equivalent of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> to `sys-snap.sh`.

If you are using bash shell, the `man bash` command has a detailed section under the section headed 'JOB CONTROL' going into more detail.

As to the name of `sys-snap.sh`, under unix file names are arbitrary (with a couple of exceptions like dynamic loader files). There is no requirement for them to have specific file extentions to make them run as a shell script, invoke other commands such as `perl` or `php` etc. It is usually used to provide clarity, that in this instance, it is `.sh` a Shell Script using the Bourne Shell `/bin/sh`.

The functional part of `sys-snap.sh` (when you look at it's contents with something like the `less` command) is the [Shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29). On the first line you will probably find one of:

```
#! /bin/sh
#! /bin/bash
#! /usr/local/bin/bash
```

or similar. In basic terms, a the command after the `#!` (such as `/bin/sh`) is ran and the contents of the rest of the script file is fed to it a line at a time. Note that the file must also be set executable with `chmod` so that you can run it as a command. If the permissions were not set, then the `shebang` has no effect, because you would either get the error:

```
bash: sys-snap.sh: command not found
```

or if you ran it by explicit path `./sys-snap.sh` (`.` meaning the current working directory) you would get:

```
bash: ./sys-snap.sh: Permission denied
```

The other alternative is to leave it without execute permissions and explicitly ask /bin/sh to run it:

```
/bin/sh sys-snap.sh &
```

Comment: this is a great answer. one possible suggestion is to also add in what `nohup` does, as it is often used in conjunction with `&` to start a process and be able to kill the shell that launched it without killing the process.

Comment: @Drav, Is it true then that `jobs` will always return empty if its the first command?

Comment: Note that using `&` at the end of a command only detaches `stdin` (but not `stdout` or `stderr`) which implies if your command/script is running in the background but writing to `stdout`, you might run into a situation where `Ctrl + c` won't stop the output but you would be able to type in commands. This is because the background process is writing to `stdout` but you can't stop it because it is not running in the foreground. More info [here](https://superuser.com/questions/972968/why-does-a-background-process-started-in-bash-print-stdout-to-screen).

Answer (score 6):

`sh` is a shell. Which shell exactly depends on the system. Example for a system that uses `bash` as its standard shell:

```
$ ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Mar 13 16:12 /bin/sh -> bash

$ sh --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.45(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

`sys-snap.sh` will be a shell script of some kind, so `sh sys-snap.sh` will execute the shell script.

`&` will cause the shell process to run in the background. Without `&` it will stay in the foreground until the script ends. The script will work either way, it's just a question of waiting for the script to end or not before executing further commands.

Answer (score 1):

Is your server in hostgator?

The script `sys-snap.sh` is a special script written by hostgator team to collect all the log files and data for the system, so they use its output in monitoring and collecting the system information.

Comment: No I am not using hostgator.

Comment: @J.Chang The script is part of cPanel which Hostgator and hundreds of other hosts use.

Comment: @472084, Which cpanel version?