# What does the ampersand in 'cat &' mean in linux?

Tags: shell, command-line

In a Linux Foundation course we're told to use `cat &` at a terminal prompt to return what appears to be the current max (used) PID. I wanted to clarify what the `&` parameter means but both `cat --help` and `man cat` turned up nothing for the ampersand parameter.

Snapshot for clarity:

[image]

Can anyone please explain what the ampersand means in this context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `&` means that you send the command to the background (also called [forking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455695/forking-multi-threaded-processes-bash)), and you are given "back" the prompt even though execution of the command continues (if any).

There is a very good discussion about this in **[this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86247/what-does-ampersand-mean-at-the-end-of-a-shell-script-line#86253).**

To know what the `max_pid` is, you can look in `/proc`:

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max 
32768
```

Or (as `root`):

```
sysctl kernel.pid_max 
kernel.pid_max = 32768
```

Comment: Cheers!  So the ampersand is not not really a parameter specific to `cat` (explaining no mention in the docs).  That helped a lot, the linked thread was useful too. Tx :)

Comment: @Alxs No. You're right. The `&` can be used with any command. It is not a parameter.

Comment: Sending command to background != Forking, please clear up your ideas first.