# Linux: How to display the output of both command who and pwd using 1 command

Tags: linux, pwd, who

I tried:

who & pwd and it output the result of pwd output: /root.

May I know if I am right?

Comment: There's no motivation for this question (and no question in the Question body); why do you need the output of *two* commands with *one* command? You fake it by writing a script that executes those two commands, then call the "one" script, but this sounds like it's a homework assignment to teach you about command-lines. Perhaps you could lay out what you've learned and why you think that we're the right people to tell you if your homework is correct.

Answer (score 2):

The `&` operator has nothing to do with executing two commands, see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86247/what-does-ampersand-mean-at-the-end-of-a-shell-script-line).

In order to execute two distinct commands on the same line, use the appropriate separator `;`:

> who; pwd